# is there anything wrong with using classnames with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there anything wrong with using classnames within styled components like so:

```
 export const StyledNav = styled.nav`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.backgroundSecondary};
  .logo-container {
    width: 201px;
    img {
      padding: 28px 24.47px 26.78px 24px;
    }
  }
`;
```

here I used the classname logo-container rather than making an entire new styled component for that.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use nesting and `SCSS`-like combinations

See their [official doc](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#coming-from-css) page, and refer to `Pseudoelements, pseudoselectors, and nesting` section.

It shows an example where, just as your snippet, one component is declared which contains nested selectors and class names.

There's nothing wrong with this approach, and it might actually be more efficient than creating every single element as a styled component.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Also, I should have checked the official docs first.